# configure jps-config.xml for external ladp connection ADF project

Tags: java, oracle, ldap, weblogic, oracle-adf

I am trying to connect to an external weblogic embeded LDAP in Oracle ADF. I've just found a good sample code that uses JpsContextFactory class, it doesnt get any url, username and password. it works with local weblogic ldap. after searching in the sources, I figured out that there is jps-config.xml file that configures the connection to ldap. I want to know how to configure this file to connect to an external ldap?

the code :

```
private void initIdStoreFactory() {
JpsContextFactory ctxFactory;
try {
    ctxFactory = JpsContextFactory.getContextFactory();
    JpsContext ctx = ctxFactory.getContext();
    LdapIdentityStore idStoreService = (LdapIdentityStore) ctx.getServiceInstance(IdentityStoreService.class);

    ldapFactory = idStoreService.getIdmFactory();

    storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_USER_SEARCH_BASES, USER_BASES);
    storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_GROUP_SEARCH_BASES, GROUP_BASES);
    storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_USER_CREATE_BASES, USER_BASES);
    storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_GROUP_CREATE_BASES, GROUP_BASES);
    storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_GROUP_SELECTED_CREATE_BASE, GROUP_BASES[0]);
    storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_USER_SELECTED_CREATE_BASE, USER_BASES[0]);
} catch (JpsException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException("Jps Exception encountered", e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ADF delegates authentication to the WebLogic security layer - so you should be setting up the mapping to the LDAP repository in the WebLogic where your ADF app is running.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SECMG/providers.htm#SECMG131